# jCarousel Auto Scroll not working, no errors

Tags: javascript, slider, jcarousel

I am trying to get jcarousel to auto scroll through some slides of mine, this is the HTML:

```
  <div id="slider">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/slides/slide_1.jpg" width="939" height="476" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="img/slides/slide_2.jpg" width="939" height="476" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- #slider -->
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#slider').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'circular'
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem, by updating jcarousel and following their examples carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the above problem, but I searched a solution for it. I used this slider on my work website and I had the same problem that you described above and I solved it by trying different thing.

I used the following code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: _init_carousel,
        buttonNextHTML: null,
        buttonPrevHTML: null
    });
});
```